# How do I add exposed function signatures to Lua Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, lua

I expose a number of C++ objects and functions to my Lua scripts via ToLua++, for example:

```
function BeginZone_Toto_Enters()

local mass = Level:GetPhysicsBodyByName("C1"):GetMass();
mass = mass * 50;
Level:GetPhysicsBodyByName("C1"):SetMass(mass);

Level:GetPhysicsBodyByName("C2"):SetActive(false);
Level:GetPhysicsBodyByName("C3"):SetActive(false);
InGameScreen:ShowMessage("Toto say meow,Toto say meowToto say meowToto say meow");

AudioManager:PlaySound("CinematicBoom");
end
```

I understand that Lua Eclipse allows autocompletion and display of function signatures (and associated descriptions) that are written in Lua, through Lua Doc. Is there a way to have similar functionality with functions that are exposed from an external source?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you may generate fake annotated Lua code from your C++ modules and feed it to the LuaEclipse.